# C++: assignment operator: pass-by-value (copy-and-swap) vs pass-by-reference

Tags: c++

Considering the advantages of [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)...

Why do we still need copy-assignment operator accepting references as the mainstream?

```
class T {
public:

    // 1: Why still commonly this?
    T& operator=(const T& rhs);

    // 2: Why not mostly that?
    T& operator=(T rhs);
}
```

There are answers suggesting to use the latter ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941677/441652) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808538/441652)).

However, most of the SO examples are still around pass-by-reference `operator=`.

Even consolidated C++ FAQ [points out](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#lint-guidelines) (yes, it's about `const`, but...):

> A `class Fred`’s copy constructor and assignment operator should have `const` in the parameter: respectively `Fred::Fred(const Fred&)` and `Fred& Fred::operator=(const Fred&)`

Obviously, copy-and-swap is implementable via pass-by-reference - it is just unnecessary if copy is to be made anyway. One may also want to avoid copying immediately on call (perform it conditionally in the body) - isn't that the less frequent case (possibly premature optimization) then?

**Shouldn't copy-and-swap with pass-by-value assignment be the default approach?**

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018053/817643) is the additional perspective you seek here.

Comment: With passing by value, you don't get the chance to do the self-assignment test (even though it isn't necessary, but may make the code run faster).

Comment: In the meantime, this question has been solved in an answer you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/3560202 pass-by-value is preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pointed to the valuable [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018053/441652):

> For example, ever wonder why high performance / often used std::types like `std::vector` and `std::string` don't use copy/swap? | [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant)

Everything I found against copy-on-swap was about optimization (avoid copy, re-purpose `lhs`):

- Obviously, self-assignment is noop.
- Another common possibility happens in (STL) *container* when `lhs` has space for `rhs`:

  ```
  class container<T> {
  public:
      // If passed by value, created copy would unconditionally increase capacity:
      T& operator=(const container<T>& rhs) {
         // ...
         if (this->capacity() >= rhs.size()) {
             // reuse capacity ...
         } else {
             // increase capacity ...
         }
      }
  }
  ```

  Notice that the hint also mentions (STL) *containers*.

The trade-off for `operator=` is:

- **by value + copy-and-swap:** simplifies (saves human time) with strong exception guarantees
- **by reference:** allows optimization (saves machine time) likely weakening guarantees

---

Related answers:

- [Why SGI STL don't use the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30397895/441652)
- [Is copy-and-swap always the best solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23918603/441652)

Answer (score 0):

Pass by reference is for avoiding unnecessary copy when you need faster executions, and pass by a const reference is when you want to pass it fast and read-only. And pass by copy is when you want to copy the object to be able to manipulate it in the course of the execution/implementation of your function.

Comment: It's logical explanation of the mechanisms, but it's not clear how copy-assignment operator benefits from other options if it is supposed to copy and assign anyway. This answer is more about differences between the mechanisms than "copy-and-swap with assignment by value" case in the question.

Comment: I think it's pretty logical to give the developers a freedom on deciding how to pass a variable: copy and do whatever you want, take it but don't modify, or take it and do whatever you want.

Comment: I agree with giving the options in general (for all situations out there). But I don't see how it makes sense to exercise every option in this specific use case. Do I even need to consider other options before picking the single one for copy-assignment operator (pass by value with copy-and-swap) every time in the first iteration? Any other option seems like optimization.

Answer (score 0):

More than it creates spurious non useful copies, second option may not work on every class as copying may be deleted.

First option have many, if not all, advantages : no copy, read-only semantic, always available.

Comment: I think that it's an exotic case when _assignment_ operator exists for read-only-semantics - what does it mean to assign to a read-only object? Also, if we delete copy-constructor, what are we implementing in copy-assignment? I don't exclude some special cases, but it doesn't seem like default one either.

Comment: it may be a mistake, I would have mean something about the `const` not about mutability.